# Problem in audioElement.src , through which i ran and play another songs .But now showing error 404(not found)

Tags: javascript, foreach, src

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('songItemPlay')).forEach(function (element) {

    element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        makeAllPlays();
        index = parseInt(e.target.id);

        e.target.classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
        e.target.classList.add('fa-circle-pause');
        audioElement.src = 'songs/${index+1}.mp3.mp3';

        audioElement.currentTime = 0;
        audioElement.play();



    });

})
```

Comment: You need to check if all the audio files are actually located at the path you mention in `src`, if they aren't you will get a 404.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

if the error is 404 it means the audio resource was not found. from the code I see you should change the sign (') with the (`) *backtick to make the string accept variables.

```
audioElement.src = `songs/${index+1}.mp3`;
```